# Unable to open openssl.cnf, but it just worked

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, debian

I'm running Debian 8. I created a signing request and then decided I wanted to change the FQDN so I deleted everything in my /ssl folder.

I then tried to run the same command again and and received the error:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
Unable to load config info from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I then reinstalled OpenSSL thinking that my fix it but it didn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall openssl?

Comment: `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` is just a symbolic link to the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

Comment: apt-get install --reinstall openssl